# Help me to do car game in C# Console

Tags: c#, console

So i need help to do my car game, my objective is make the road always appear in the console and keep the lifes in the top of the screen, i already have the function that makes a random from the type of road that appears(function - "DesenharEstrada();"), but i cant keep the lifes printed on the top of the screen because they are inside a "while" and they disappears when the road leave the screen limit.
I hope you understand my question, my english is not so good, sorry.

```
        int lifes= 3;
        string[] road = { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," "};
        int a=0;

        while (lifes> 0)
        {
            Console.Title = "Road To Hell \n- Vidas: " + vidas;

            road = DesenharEstrada();

            escreveAvermelho(road[0]);
            escreveFundoAcinza(road[1] + road[2]);
            escreveAvermelho(road[3]);
            escreveFundoAcinza(road[4] + road[5]);
            escreveAvermelho(road[6]);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);

            A_cores(ConsoleColor.Yellow, "Vidas: " + vidas + "\n");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
            //para o delay não ficar negativo
                if (delay < 30)
                {
                    //lifes= lifes - 1;
                    delay = 30;
                }
                else if(delay < 100 && a < 3000 )
                {
                    delay = delay - 1;
                }

        }

        //Fim do Jogo
        Console.Clear();

        writeCol(string.Format(@"
              ___           ___           ___           ___     
             /  /\         /  /\         /__/\         /  /\    
            /  /:/_       /  /::\       |  |::\       /  /:/_   
           /  /:/ /\     /  /:/\:\      |  |:|:\     /  /:/ /\  
          /  /:/_/::\   /  /:/~/::\   __|__|:|\:\   /  /:/ /:/_ 
         /__/:/__\/\:\ /__/:/ /:/\:\ /__/::::| \:\ /__/:/ /:/ /\
         \  \:\ /~~/:/ \  \:\/:/__\/ \  \:\~~\__\/ \  \:\/:/ /:/
          \  \:\  /:/   \  \::/       \  \:\        \  \::/ /:/ 
           \  \:\/:/     \  \:\        \  \:\        \  \:\/:/  
            \  \::/       \  \:\        \  \:\        \  \::/   
             \__\/         \__\/         \__\/         \__\/    
              ___                        ___           ___     
             /  /\          ___         /  /\         /  /\    
            /  /::\        /__/\       /  /:/_       /  /::\   
           /  /:/\:\       \  \:\     /  /:/ /\     /  /:/\:\  
          /  /:/  \:\       \  \:\   /  /:/ /:/_   /  /:/~/:/  
         /__/:/ \__\:\  ___  \__\:\ /__/:/ /:/ /\ /__/:/ /:/___
         \  \:\ /  /:/ /__/\ |  |:| \  \:\/:/ /:/ \  \:\/:::::/
          \  \:\  /:/  \  \:\|  |:|  \  \::/ /:/   \  \::/~~~~ 
           \  \:\/:/    \  \:\__|:|   \  \:\/:/     \  \:\     
            \  \::/      \__\::::/     \  \::/       \  \:\    
             \__\/           ~~~~       \__\/         \__\/    

        You made lines. Press Esc to exit"), ConsoleColor.Red);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Can you translate name of your functions at least? what does "escreveAvermelho" mean? beside can you give an screenshot of how your game is going to look like?

Comment: @Sachamora I'd guess write in red, but not especially helpful.

Comment: Is the functions are "escreveAvermelho" = "write in red" and "escreveFundoAcinza" = write background gray.

Answer (score 1):

I would clear the screen and rewrite everything after moving a single line - this might be very slow, but this isn't the way the console was intended to be used.

Comment: Can you give me one example please?

Answer (score 0):

I would create separate classes for your car and road. Give your road class a method that draws only the road, the road and the car never intercepts so you can draw it without messing with the car. Then also make a class for your car and add a method that will draw your car.